# HTML5 video element width 70%

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to have video element which would be only 70% width of the screen, but i'm strugling to maintain height aspect ratio 100%. Now i have full width video as a background.

I am using bootstrap v4.

```
<body>
 <video poster="assets/img/gpd.jpg" id="bgvid" playsinline autoplay muted loop>
<source src="assets/video/gpd_video.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
<div class="site-wrapper">
 <div class="site-wrapper-inner">
  <div class="cover-container">
    <div class="masthead clearfix">
      <div class="inner">
        <h3 class="masthead-brand">Cover</h3>
        <nav class="nav nav-masthead">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mastfoot">
      <div class="inner">
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
 video { 
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;   
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    background-size: cover;
    transition: 1s opacity;
}
```

I would like to have something like this as a result:

[image: Wanted result]

Is it possible ?

Comment: If you don't have a parent with a specific height then min-height: 100% wont work. try setting min-height: 200px

Comment: Why don't you use max-width. Set max-width:70vw.

Comment: it is much closer what i want with max-width:70vw, but the video still doesnt fill the whole area

Comment: try this [link] http://getbootstrap.com/components/#responsive-embed it will help you to adjust the ratio of video and use `col-lg-8` to make it 70% of your screen

Comment: Width is fine now, but the height still getting adjusted to like 60% of body height.

Comment: Can you add the code for the menu, poster size, and right background..

Comment: Do you want to keep original aspect ratio or do you care about stretching?

Comment: I think it does not matter as long as it would look good. I want to fill that area with video and then overlay it with some transparent background and probably add text to that area.

Answer (score 1):

```
video { 
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
```

> **min-width: 70%;**

```
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;   
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    background-size: cover;
    transition: 1s opacity;
}
```

//I would recommend you to use this css , by setting min-width:70% your video take only 70% of your viewport :)